# Make alert message with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to put up an message error when user clicks into the events.

This is my calendar :

[image]

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
{
    var status = false;

    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    { 
        if (e.EventID > 0)
        {
            // Update the event
            var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (v != null)
            {
                v.EventTitle = e.EventTitle;
                v.StartDate = e.StartDate;
                v.EndDate = e.EndDate;
                v.EventDescription = e.EventDescription;
                v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Events.Add(e);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
}
```

When the user clicks into events, I want him to receive an alert :

```
function SaveEvent(data) {
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/home/SaveEvent',
              data: data,
              success: function (data) {
                   if (data.status) {
                       // Refresh the calender
                       FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                       $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                   }
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert('Failed');
              }
          })
      }
 })
```

Can I find someone who worked with full calendar before?

Comment: What are events exactly? The blue/green item on your calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I have some expirience with DevExpress and Telerik scheduler controls.

I assume what you are trying to achieve.

In order to display alert when event is clicked you need to add onclick event listener for your rendered html element(your event)

For example:

```
<div id="your-event-id-from-db" onclick="showInfo(this)">
    <p>12 am event text</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showInfo(element){
        var id = element.id;
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

You can also use unique event id to do AJAX call to server and get event data like start date,end date,desription and so on... if you want to populate modal for editing event.